# Coldfusion regular expressions, get content out of html tags

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I currently have the following HTML in a string I try to parse to `reReplaceNoCase`:

```
<blockquote class="id-1241">
<p>Stuff</p>
</blockquote>
<p>Test</p>
<blockquote class="id-2441">
<p>More stuff</p>
<blockquote>
<p>Test</p>
</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

I would like to eventually transform this into:

```
{{1241}}
<p>Test</p>
{{2441}}
```

So I want to take out the id from the blockquote class, and use that to replace the blockquote. I'm currently using `reReplaceNoCase` to do this, but I notice that it ends the regular expression at the end of the last closing blockquote tag, instead of the one that is 'connected' to the correct blockquote opening tag, causing the following result:

```
{{1241}}
```

This is what I am currently using:

```
reply = reReplaceNoCase(reply, '<blockquote class="id-([0-9]+)">(.*)</blockquote>', '{{\1}}', 'ALL');
```

Does anyone have a better example with a result that is what I want? I think I could use a loop with reFind, or something along those lines, but this seems to be too much of a hassle, I'd have the idea that there were easier ways to do this, and also with better performance.

If possible, I'd like to avoid using Java directly as well.

Comment: Can the nested block quotes contain any class attributes ?

Comment: No, the nested ones won't have any class attributes. (at least, the blockquotes - other tags inside the blockquotes can)

Comment: I am afraid this can't be done because you can't parse nested structures with regular expressions, if you found someone who could solve this for using only a regular expression please let me know.

Comment: You _can_ parse nested structures with regex - you just can't do arbitrary nesting with a _single_ regex. Not a sane one, anyhow. Anyhow, **the correct tool for this task is a HTML parser**, which will make it pretty simple. Take a look at [jSoup](http://jsoup.org).

Comment: I don't like doing this client-side though; I would like to do it server-side. Isn't there a possiblity to parse it as XML? (note I'm using CF8 and CF10 on some servers)

Comment: jSoup is server-side, and a billion times better than CF's built-in XML parsing.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, why don't you make the JSoup suggestion an answer rather than a comment? It is, after all, probably the best answer to be expected here.

Comment: I don't like wasting my time and I was fairly sure the response below was coming; I can't be bothered trying to explain the foolishness of the stance "we don't like to depend on libraries". :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery - although I said I didn't like to do it client-side, the company I work at also doesn't like to depend too much on libraries - we already have quite a bunch.

I don't think I need to explain how I did it in jQuery, since it's pretty straight forward there, and a million tutorials already exist on changing elements in jQuery.

Comment: Posting the code here would be more useful to future readers than telling them to "google for the answer". If you do not have time, you may just want to delete the thread.